# Why prerequisites doesn't show framework 2.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

In control panel> Add or remove programs it is showing microsoft framework 2.0 service pack 2 but when i create setup then in prerequisites it is not showing me the option to select framework 2.0.

I also tried installing framework 2.0 again but it shows me the error

```
Setup cannot continue because this version of .NET Framework is incompatible with a previously installed one.
```

What is the solution of it ?

Comment: @CodeCaster Please look at my comment at taht post.

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to do in this question.

Comment: I made an application and i want to select framework 2.0 as my prerequisites but i am not getting the option for it.

Comment: Is your project built to target .NET 2.0?

Comment: i don't want to download the framework from internet on target machine i want to give the framework to the client with application setup as we select option "download prerequisite with the same location as my application" from prerequisite window, then it gives framework also with the setup.

Comment: yes, i made it using 2.0 and if i create setup on another machine where framework 2.0 and VS 2003 is install there it gives me the option for selecting 2.0 also

Comment: I'm not sure about the base problem but concerning the installation, you should take a look at [this topic](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-windows_update/error-setup-cannot-continue-because-this-version/4bc7b9d8-7680-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5)